# jmeter-maven-plugin : how to download required plugin used by jmeter testplan when execute mvn verify

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-maven-plugin

I use non default thread group/plugins in test plan, when running 
`mvn clean verify` 
maven generate an error

```
missing class com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException:
[INFO] ---- Debugging information ----
[INFO] cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException
```

However in maven command line console i saw that download dependency = true

```
target\jmeter\lib\ext with downloadExtensionDependencies set to true ...
target\jmeter\lib\junit with downloadLibraryDependencies set to true
target\jmeter\lib with downloadLibraryDependencies set to true ...
```

This is my pom.xml

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jmeter.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testFilesIncluded>
                        <jMeterTestFile>google.jmx</jMeterTestFile>
                    </testFilesIncluded>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jmeter</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jmeter-check-results</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>results</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Question:

1. What should i put in the  so that jmeter-maven-plugin will download required plugin? 
   (usually we use jmeter plugin manager to download on the UI)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your test relies on [Custom Thread Groups](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Start/#Thread-Groups) you will need to add few lines to your `pom.xml` in order to tell JMeter Maven Plugin to download and install this plugin, your configuration should look something like:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jmeter.maven.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <jmeterExtensions>
                    <artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-casutg:2.5</artifact>
                </jmeterExtensions>
                <testFilesIncluded>
                    <jMeterTestFile>google.jmx</jMeterTestFile>
                </testFilesIncluded>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jmeter</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>jmeter-check-results</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>results</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

More information:

- [Adding additional libraries to the classpath](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Adding-additional-libraries-to-the-classpath)
- [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui)

Comment: I'm still confused where we should use plugin in testPlanLibraries, jmeterExtensions or junitLibraries? All library in https://jmeter-plugins.org/ is a testPlanLibraries? Some of those do not have maven artifact name in jmeter-plugins.org